# Can't use underscore in algorithm2e caption?

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I have a LaTeX document using the `algorithm2e` package. It used to work before I upgraded to texlive (it's the Debian version 2012.20120516-1 -- some snapshot from 2012, if I understand correctly).

The problem is that now it seems that I can't use underscores in captions of algorithms, functions, and so on...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
This is ``A''
\caption{method\_A}
\end{procedure}

\end{document}
```

When I try to process the above document with pdflatex, I see this error:

```
Runaway argument?
method\_A@\endcsname ##1{\FuncSty {\algocf@captname method\_A@(}\ArgSty \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \algocf@captname was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.11 

?
```

What does this error mean, and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `procedure` environment supplied by [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) has a strict requirement in terms of its caption. From the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf):

> ...the syntax of the `\caption` command is restricted as follow: you MUST put a name
>   followed by 2 braces like this “Name()”. You can put arguments inside the braces and
>   text after. If no argument is given, the braces will be removed in the title.

As such, you're required to use something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
This is ``A''
\caption{proc(method\_A)}
\end{procedure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a bit strange (particularly because C function names may have underscores -- and usually do), but I can rework the document to not use those.

Comment: @Jay: Sure. Of course, a completely different question would be to change the caption to meet your needs. Using `procedure` or `function` forces a certain requirement and also output. Asking [follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/5764) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: @Werner fyi, I added related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680982/how-to-make-procedure-name-with-underscore-using-algorithm2e) with reference to your answer here.