# algorithm2e, function, procedure, \par, error

Tags: algorithm2e

This is fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    $x \gets x$\;
    \caption{Identity}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

But this, which uses the predefined environment "function" (p. 4 of the manual)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{function}
    $x \gets x$\;
    \caption{Identity}
\end{function}

\end{document}
```

produces this error

```
Runaway argument?
Identity@\endcsname ##1{\FuncSty {\algocf@captname Identity@(}\ArgSty \ETC.
./sandbox.tex:10: Paragraph ended before \algocf@captname was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.10 

? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
./sandbox.tex:10: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.10 

)
! Emergency stop.
```

I use TexShop which (I believe) compiles with

```
simpdftex latex --maxpfb --extratexopts "-file-line-error -synctex=1"
```

Any help would be appreciate, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Very much related, if not a duplicate: [Can't use underscore in `algorithm2e` caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58819/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in page 17 of the documentation (talking about the `procedure` environment, but the same remark applies to `function`):

> the syntax of the `\caption` command is restricted as follow: you MUST
>   put a name followed by 2 braces like this `Name()`. You can put
>   arguments inside the braces and text after. If no argument is given,
>   the braces will be removed in the title.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{function}
    $x \gets x$\;
    \caption{Identity()}
\end{function}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that in the manual.

However, my precise problem is that my algorithm makes recursive calls and I need to make this clear in the algorithm environment. In the very least I want to move the caption to the top but

    \usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}

produces (bizarrely)

    LaTeX Error: Unknown option `boxedruled' for package `algorithm2e'.

despite it also being a valid option from the manual.