# How to make procedure name with underscore using `algorithm2e`?

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

Using answer given in [Procedure name with small caps in algorithm2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218399/procedure-name-with-small-caps-in-algorithm2e) shows how to make procedure name all small caps in algorithm2e.

But I want to add `_` between the names, as it is long name. Adding `\_` in the name gives error.

What other options are there? Here is MWE that works, and below that I show the one that does not work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[algosection, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\SetProcNameSty{textsc}
\SetProcArgSty{textsc}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

\begin{procedure}
\caption{secondorderseriessolver()}
\Input{ode $y''=f(x,y,y')$}
\Output{solution}

\If{$f(x,y,y')$ analytic at $x=0$}
{
   process\;

   \textbf{return}
}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the name of the procedure to `\caption{second_order_series_solver()}` or `\caption{second\_order\_series\_solver()}` both fail.

Then I tried the trick given in   [Can't use underscore in algorithm2e caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58819/cant-use-underscore-in-algorithm2e-caption)  but this produced the following

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\SetProcNameSty{textsc}
\SetProcArgSty{textsc}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

\begin{procedure}
\caption{(second\_order\_series\_solver)}
\Input{ode $y''=f(x,y,y')$}
\Output{solution}

\If{$f(x,y,y')$ analytic at $x=0$}
{
   process\;

   \textbf{return}
}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

Which produced this

[image]

Which is close to what I want, but not exactly. I wanted it to look like the first but with underscores like the second version. The second version has `(..)` around it.

How to make name of procedure contain underscore?  Btw, having small caps is not important at all for me. I just used it from the example given. I simply want the add `_` between the names of the proc itself (not its arguments as given in the second answer below).

TL 2022

Comment: I guess the issue is the longer underscore? I can't replicate that issue with the code you provide ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI0e2.png)).

Comment: @Werner  I think I did not explain myself well. Yes, I get same output as show in the link you gave. But I want the name of the procedure to have `_` and not the names inside `(....)`. i.e. I want same output as the first example shows, but with underscores. Your solution gives that but it also adds `(...)` to the name as you can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unclear reasons, `algorithm2e` stores the argument of `\caption` as a `\csname` and obviously this fails when `\_` is used.

The code is found in `\SetKwFunction` and `\SetKwArray`. What this is for is really unclear.

At least you can remove the error by making `\_` legal inside `\csname`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[algosection, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy{\legacyunderscore}{\_}
\renewcommand{\_}{\ifincsname_\else\legacyunderscore\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
% up to %%% should be either inside procedure or in the preamble
\SetProcNameSty{textsc}
\SetProcArgSty{textsc}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
%%%
\caption{second\_order\_series\_solver()}
\Input{ode $y''=f(x,y,y')$}
\Output{solution}

\If{$f(x,y,y')$ analytic at $x=0$}
{
   process\;

   \textbf{return}
}
\end{procedure}

\end{document}
```